# Alternative for jssor event $EVT_PARK

Tags: jssor

```
    jssor_slider_video.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, function(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
        videoJssorJwPlayer();
    });
```

The above code which I used to do event related but this won't work as I expected (I like to call the method `videoJssorJwPlayer()` on from loading itself but this event was triggered from the second slide also I know the reason from second slide only the `$EVT_PARK` fired).

But my necessity is need an event which will trigger from jssor instantiation itself.

Tried:

```
jssor_slider_video.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_LOAD_START, function(slideIndex) {
    console.log(slideIndex);
});
```

But it won't log any thing in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jssor Slider parks at slide 0 (specified by $StartIndex option) at the beginning.
You can call 'videoJssorJwPlayer()' once it initialized then.

```
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        function OnSlidePark(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
            if (slideIndex == 0) {
                //hit the first slide
                videoJssorJwPlayer();
            }
        }

        OnSlidePark(0, -1);

        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, OnSlidePark);
```